# Можно ли для класса сделать только 1 свойство?

Tags: c#

Внутри поле-структура, содержащая оценки.

Можно ли для класса сделать только 1 свойство? (ну или обойтись функцией какой-нибудь) Ибо делают они тоже самое, разные только названия.

```
public int this[string name]
{
    get
    {
        if (name == nameof(Marks.Inf)) return Marks.Inf;
        if (name == nameof(Marks.Math)) return Marks.Math;
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: совсем непонятно что именно есть, и что ты хочешь получить. Добавь пример своих трех классов, и пример того, что ты хочешь от них получить

Comment: Есть 3 класса. У каждого из них, в качестве поля - своя собственная структура с оценками. (т.е 3 разных структуры)
В каждом из трех классов определены свойства для получения\изменения полей из данной структуры. 
Код свойств - выполняет абсолютно одно и тоже, разница между свойствами - думаю видна, она только в имени поля.

Comment: Под примером, я имел ввиду _пример кода этих классов_, а не комментарий, повторяющий в сжатом виде текст вопроса. Для редактирования вопроса используй кнопку [edit]

Comment: *Можно ли для класса сделать только 1 свойство?* Да. Сделайте индексатор для класса. Входной параметр — название предмета. Выходной параметр — оценка

Comment: Вот. То что и имелось ввиду, скорее всего. Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Dictionary<string, int> Marks { get; set; } = 
  Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: как приведенный код относится к вопросу?

Comment: @Grundy приведенный код относится к вопросу так, что  отвечает на "Можно ли для класса сделать только 1 свойство?"

Comment: Ну, такой вариант однозначно подходит, но соваться туда пока я не стану. Рановато еще. 
Мне просто говорили что с использованием nameof можно как-то через функцию сделать то, что я собственно изложил выше.

Comment: @Igor, из ответа это совсем не очевидно, неизвестно почему _Dictionary_, почему именно такие типы, зачем _StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase_?

Comment: @TorSen _Мне просто говорили что с использованием nameof можно как-то через функцию сделать то, что я собственно изложил выше._ - теперь стало еще больше непонятно что именно ты хочешь

Comment: @TorSen "но соваться туда пока я не стану. Рановато еще" как раз самое время. Словарь существенно быстрее вашей цепочки if по имени или switch...case, да и изменение набора оцениваемых предметов без переписывания кода происходит.